Bind mount alternative inside an unprivileged docker container
I want to run multiple processes with different views on /some/path, so that one sees /other/path1 and another sees /other/path2.
I learned that this can be achieved through unshare and mount --bind. But I am inside an unprivilegded container that does not allow the required syscalls.
Are there any alternative methods to do this? Maybe some tool that can hijack the open syscall?

I found an awesome tool call proot that can do exactly what I want.
It also provides statically linked binary that can simply drop-in-and-use.

PRoot is a user-space implementation of chroot, mount --bind, and binfmt_misc. This means that users don't need any privileges or setup to do things like using an arbitrary directory as the new root filesystem, making files accessible somewhere else in the filesystem hierarchy, or executing programs built for another CPU architecture transparently through QEMU user-mode. Also, developers can use PRoot as a generic Linux process instrumentation engine thanks to its extension mechanism, see CARE for an example. Technically PRoot relies on ptrace, an unprivileged system-call available in every Linux kernel.

